java hibernate integration test delimiter error
MOST IMPORTANT UPDATE:
I realized these tests are getting the data.sql file from /main/resources/data.sql and ALSO from /test/resources/data.sql.
How can I limit this to /test/resources/data.sql
How can I configure hibernate to get from the test? Even tho my unit tests are under /test/ hibernate is not taking test directory's data.sql for configuration... ??
I get this error in hibernate h2, as I want to do integration test
create table user (
    id bigint not null auto_increment,
    coins bigint,
    country varchar(255),
    level integer not null,
    primary key (id)
) engine=InnoDB" via JDBC [Syntax error in SQL statement "\000a    create table [*]user (\000a        id bigint not null auto_increment,\000a        coins bigint,\000a        country varchar(255),\000a        level integer not null,\000a        primary key (id)\000a    ) engine=InnoDB"; expected "identifier";]

tells me it expectes an identifier, but indeed in my data.sql file that it is fetching from I do have ; delimiter:
data.sql
create table if not exists  user (
    id bigint not null auto_increment,
    coins bigint,
    country varchar(255),
    level integer not null,
    primary key (id)
);

As a side note, I have multiple create table statements in my data.sql file... maybe that is a reason?
And these are my application properties, under /main/test/resources
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:h2:mem:test;MODE=MySQL;
spring.datasource.driver-class-name=org.h2.Driver
spring.datasource.username=
spring.datasource.password=
# We add the MySQL Dialect so that it understands and generates the query based on MySQL
spring.jpa.database-platform=org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect

spring.h2.console.enabled=true
spring.jpa.defer-datasource-initialization=true
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=update
spring.jpa.hibernate.naming.implicit-strategy=org.hibernate.boot.model.naming.ImplicitNamingStrategyLegacyJpaImpl
spring.jpa.hibernate.naming.physical-strategy=org.hibernate.boot.model.naming.PhysicalNamingStrategyStandardImpl
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.format_sql=true
spring.jpa.hibernate.naming-strategy=org.hibernate.cfg.ImprovedNamingStrategy

spring.sql.init.mode=always

What is the fix to this ? Please help..
Extra question(answer optional): When  I insert data into the table with h2 for my integration test (I use mvcmock) do I need to clean the table after each unit test? Or does it clean itself already (assuming it is in memory)
also, in case needed, my test interface from AppControllerTests
@SpringBootTest(webEnvironment = SpringBootTest.WebEnvironment.MOCK)
@AutoConfigureMockMvc
public class TournamentControllerTests {
    @Autowired
    private MockMvc mockMvc;

    @MockBean
    private TournamentService tournamentService;

    @Test
    @Sql(value = "classpath:mysql-db-dumb.sql", executionPhase = BEFORE_TEST_METHOD)
    public void getEmployeeByIdAPI() throws Exception
    {

UPDATE:
https://www.baeldung.com/spring-boot-h2-jdbcsqlsyntaxerrorexception-expected-identifier
this site states that user is a reserved keyword in h2, and should be used as "user" with quotes. Yet I tried using "user" but still getting the same error.

Spring Boot loads the SQL init file from the classpath. In your case it uses src/main/resources/data.sql. If you want to use a different one in your tests you should:

Rename the one in src/test/resources to data-test.sql
Add this property to the src/test/resources/application.properties file

spring.sql.init.data-locations=classpath:data-test.sql

Based on: Spring Boot Documentation

thanks for the advice,  I edited the src/test/resources/application.properties and have now a file src/test/resourcesdata-test.sql yet I get the error No data scripts found at location 'data-test.sql'

maybe it is a different location, or my properties are broken; I tried both under /test/resources and /main/resources

My bad. Please check the corrected answer.
